# CSS: why is the "div#container" syntax used instead of just #container?

Tags: css, hash, syntax

I'm seeing this "div#container" syntax being used in CSS and I'm wondering how it works. Anybody has a resource for it?

Comment: I found this link that says this is called tag-qualifying and that it's bad:
[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/)
Why then is it used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as being a unique reference as mentioned above, IDs increase specificity (I highly recommend you read this article or one similar http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/, understanding specificity in css will make your life easier).

Ill try to explain with a short example - take the following:

```
  div#item { background: blue}

  <div id="item" class="item">Hello world</div>
```

This says make any divs with the ID 'container' blue, but if you then add the following styles after it in your stylesheet

```
  #item {background: purple} 
  .item {background: green}
```

the assumption is that the container would be green because stylesheets are cascading and the class with green background comes last. However this isn't the case, an ID has greater precedence and will override a class even if the class comes later. Additionally the item would not be purple because you have added the div before the id earlier on. Having the div and the id increases the specificity further.

People often specify items in css like this: div#container to add extra importance to the style or to specifically state that only DIVS with the id container can be blue.

I would recommend not doing this it becomes harder to override and the style then be comes unusable if you want to make something else have the background blue. So for example the following would not make the paragraph blue because the style specifically states divs.

```
 div#item {background: blue;}

 <p id="item">Hello world</p>
```

If you wanted to override the div#item to be pink instead of blue you might have to do something like the following.

```
  div#item.item {background: pink}
```

This doesn't seem that bad but when you start building complex websites this can make your css really clunky.

My advice is to make your css as re-usable as possible e.g. the following can be easily overwritten and reused on any tag.

```
 .item { background: blue;}
```

Hope that helps! Seriously read up on css specificity, it will really help you out.

Answer (score 0):

From the CSS standard itself, [a chart of selector syntaxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

The one you're looking for is near the end:

```
E#myid  Matches any E element with ID equal to "myid".
```

In other words, that selector will match `<div id="container">`.

Of course, id values must be unique, so you shouldn't need to specify an element name. You could use `*#container` or just `#container`, and many people do. Putting the element name in explicitly might be considered more self-documenting.

Comment: ID values do *not* need to be document-unique (per HTML5 and allowed in many HTML4 implementations, fsvo.)

Comment: @user2864740: They are *supposed* to be unique, but browsers accept all sorts of garbage. "What makes attributes of type ID special is that no two such attributes can have the same value in a conformant document, regardless of the type of the elements that carry them; whatever the document language, an ID typed attribute can be used to uniquely identify its element." (From the CSS3 Selector specification I happened to have open.)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

Try to look at this . This will teach you, how this works.

```
#abc {
text-align: center;
color: blue; }
```

now anywhere you use #abc text will be aligned center and text color will be blue.

You can also customize it as per your needs.